Largest singular value of bidiagonal matrix representing central differences
The matrix
$$G_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}$$
has eigenvalues $(-i,i)$ and the largest singular value is 1.
The matrix
$$G_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    -1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & -1 &0 
    \end{bmatrix}$$
has eigenvalues $(-i \sqrt{2}, 0, i \sqrt{2})$ so that largest singular value is $\sqrt{2}$. The matrix
$$G_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    -1 & 0 & 1 &0\\
    0 & -1 & 0 &1 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}.$$
has eigenvalues $(\pm 0.61834 i, \pm 1.61803i)$ so the largest singular value is $1.61803$. The matrix
$$G_5 = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 1 &0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 &0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 &0&-1&0
    \end{bmatrix}.$$ has eigenvalues $(\pm \sqrt{3}i, \pm i, 0)$ and thus largest singular value is $\sqrt{3}$. Let's play this game further, what will be the largest singular value for the matrix $G_k$ with this structure?
$$G_k = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
    -1 & 0 & 1 & \dots &0\\
    0 & -1 & 0 & \dots &0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & 1\\
    0 & 0 &0&-1&0
    \end{bmatrix}.$$
Natural question also is whether with $k\to \infty$ largest singular value $\sigma_k \to \infty$ as well? Because the matrix has a structure of differentiation operator with central differences, this question has implications for the operator norm of the gradient.
Interestingly enough, gradient defined not by central differences will have operator norm, which does not depend on $k$, see Largest eigenvalue of simple bidiagonal matrix.
I have found $\sigma_6=1.80194$, $\sigma_7=1.84776$ so my theory is that with $k\to \infty$ $\sigma_k \to 2$.

This is a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix of dimension $k$.  Wikipedia tells us that the eigenvalues are
$\pm 2 i \cos \frac{ m \pi}{k+1}$ ; $m = 1 \ldots k$. The largest absolute value is obtained for $m=1$, giving  $2 \cos \frac{  \pi}{k+1}$ . For very large $k$, you are approaching 2.
